# How does $2^{3b}$ - $2^{(a-1)b}$ = 0?

Tags: proof-verification

I have a proof and am unsure of the algebra to get from Step 2.) to Step 3.) below.

When I subtract ($2^b$ + $2^{2b}$ + $2^{3b}$ + $2^{ab}$) - (1 + $2^b$ + $2^{2b}$ + $2^{(a-1)b}$) I do the following:

Remove the ellipse and assume 4 elements in each sequence
($2^b$ + $2^{2b}$ + $2^{3b}$ + $2^{ab}$) - (1 + $2^b$ + $2^{2b}$ + $2^{(a-1)b}$)

Distribute the negative:
    $2^b$ + $2^{2b}$ + $2^{3b}$ + $2^{ab}$ - 1 - $2^b$ - $2^{2b}$ - $2^{(a-1)b}$

Subtract/remove opposite like terms:
        + $2^{3b}$ + $2^{ab}$ - 1 - $2^{(a-1)b}$

And this is as far as I could take it since I see no more like terms (same base/exponent combinations). But working backwards, I do see Step 3.) shows result $2^{ab}$ - 1 and so if I remove this I am left with:
    $2^{3b}$ - $2^{(a-1)b}$.

So now this implies that $2^{3b}$ - $2^{(a-1)b}$ should cancel each other out but I don't see how to do this because although they both have the same base, they don't have the same exponent.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Theorem 3.7.1. Suppose n is an integer larger than 1 and n is not prime. Then $2^n$ - 1 is not prime. Proof. Since n is not prime, there are positive integers a and b such that a < n, b < n, and n = ab. Let x = $2^b$ - 1 and y = 1 + $2^b$ + $2^{2b}$ +· · ·+ $2^{(a-1)b}$. Then

xy = ($2^b$ - 1) · (1 + $2^b$ + $2^{2b}$ +···+$2^{(a-1)b}$)

Step 1.) = $2^b$ · (1 + $2^b$ + $2^{2b}$ +···+$2^{(a-1)b}$) - (1 + $2^b$ + $2^{2b}$ +···+$2^{(a-1)b}$)

Step 2.) = ($2^b$ + $2^{2b}$ + $2^{3b}$ +···+$2^{ab}$) - (1 + $2^b$ + $2^{2b}$ +···+ $2^{(a-1)b}$)

Step 3.) = $2^{ab}$ - 1

Step 4.) = $2^n$ - 1.

Comment: This isn't clear.  Obviously $2^{3b}\neq 2^{(a-1)b}$ in general so there must be more information.  What is it?

Comment: Your main issue is that you forget the "$\ldots$" in both set of parentheses. What you think is $1+2^b + 2^{2b}+2^{(a-1)b}$ is actually written as $1+2^b + 2^{2b}+\ldots+2^{(a-1)b}$, i.e. **there are all the terms in between as well**: $$$1+2^b + 2^{2b}+\ldots+2^{(a-1)b}= 1+2^b + 2^{2b}+2^{3b}+2^{4b}\ldots+2^{(a-2)b}+2^{(a-1)b}$$

Comment: Well, for $a=5$ and $b=1$, the left hand side is $2^3=8$, but the right hand side is $2^4=16$, so it's unlikely your proof that $2^{3b}-2^{(a-1)b}=0$ is correct.

Comment: Thanks guys.  This proof comes from the book "How to prove it".  It is the first proof in chapter 3.7 so I would guess it is correct unless the author made a mistake but I assume he didn't

Comment: @egreg The key is that what the OP wrote at the top, and what the proof states at the bottom, ar *not* the same thing.

Comment: @maybedave The proof **is** correct. The way you read it, however, is not -- you cannot "ignore" the $\ldots$ which are there to indicate there are many more terms in between. The difference is the same as if I wrote $1+2+3+\ldots+(n-1)+n$, and you read it as $1+2+3+(n-1)+n$.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is, literally, that you are right: there is no reason for which what you write should cancel to $0$: $2^{3b}-2^{(a-1)b}\neq 0$ in general.

---

The reason for which the proof **is** correct, however, is that what you did write at the top of your question *misrepresents what the proof says*.

Your main issue is that you forgot the "$\ldots$" in both set of parentheses. What you think is $1+2^b + 2^{2b}+2^{(a-1)b}$ is actually written as $1+2^b + 2^{2b}+\ldots+2^{(a-1)b}$, i.e. **there are all the terms in between as well**: $$1+2^b + 2^{2b}+\ldots+2^{(a-1)b}= 1+2^b + 2^{2b}+2^{3b}+2^{4b}\ldots+2^{(a-2)b}+2^{(a-1)b}$$

Since these terms are in both sets of parentheses, they will cancel, leaving only $2^{ab}-1$ in the end.

Comment: So I removed the ellipse trying to find one case where I could perform the algebra.  You highlighting this shows me that I did screw it up.  If I set a = 4 to be my one case then we have 

($2^b$ + $2^{2b}$ + $2^{3b}$ + $2^{4b}$) - (1 + $2^b$ + $2^{2b}$ + $2^{(4-1)b}$) which leaves $2^{4b}$ - 1.  NOW I GET IT.  THANK YOU!!!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @ Clement C.  Thank you!!!